# Fixing price of Tokens to USD, but buying in ETH?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, erc20, chainlink

```
  function _getTokenAmount(uint weiAmount) internal override view returns(uint256) {
      super._getTokenAmount(weiAmount);
      int currentPrice = priceFeed.getLatestPrice();
      uint weiToEightDec = weiAmount / (10 * 10 ** 10);
      uint exchangeRatePerWei = 1000000000000000000 / uint(currentPrice)  ;
      uint usdAmount = weiToEightDec* exchangeRatePerWei;
      uint amountToGive = usdAmount * 25;
      return(amountToGive);
  }
```

The decimals are throwing me off.  I want to get the exchange rate of 1 ETH to USD first, then get the exchange rate from that.  Using the exchange rate, I will multiply it by the amount of ETH given to calculate the dollar amount, then use that to give the correct amount of tokens ($1 @ 0.04 = 25 per dollar).

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you give an example value of the `currentPrice` and what it represents? Price of ETH in USD, including some amout of decimals, ...?

Comment: Sure, it is the price of 1 ETH in USD with 8 decimals, from Chainlink's Oracle feed.